# Best Way to Have Transparent Navbar that is positioned on hero section in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have this navbar component that sits above my hero section. My problem is if I make the background transparent, it will just be white instead of being on top of my hero image.

Right now it looks like this
[image]

Here is the code for the navbar

```
      export const Nav = styled.nav`
        background: transparent;
        height: 80px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0.5rem calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);
        z-index: 10;
      `;
```

In my App.js the navbar just stacks on top of the hero section

```
           function App() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <Hero />
          </Router>
        );
      }
```

So no matter what it will always be located on top.

The only alternative I've found is to add

`margin-top: -80px` to my hero section, but I feel like there's a better way to do it.

[image]

The negative margin essentially does the trick, and you can see the navbar is over the hero image, but now I lose -80px of the hero section and it doesn't display the full 100% of it.

Any ideas of how to create a navbar that is located on top of a hero section without using negative margins?

Comment: You can use `position: absolute | fixed` to do the trick. It would be great if you could provide a runnable example or GitHub repo that can be used to repro the above issue

Comment: I tried that but the issue is my entire design doesn't use positioning so it ruins my entire navbar design cause it has flexbox implemented

Comment: If you could provide a minimal reproducible example. So I can repro it locally, I might able to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
At your Hero section keep `margin-top: -80px` and instead of `height: 100%` put `height: 100vh`; Tell me if it helped